# Data range selection does not work properly with year and month filter from combobox in ms access forms

Tags: ms-access

I have a form in MS Access where I can filter dates using the date range ( "from:" and "to:" as combobox, they are called in code as "cboStart" and "cboEnd"). When you click on the Combobox, you will see 02.2021, 05.2021, 06.2021, 01.2022, 02.2022, 03.2022 etc. They show all options that exist (it's just showing the values ​​that exist in the query, I'm calling the dates  from the query)

Code is (I found this in youtube):

```
Private Sub cboEnd_AfterUpdate()

UpdateFilter
Me.Requery
End Sub


Private Sub cboStart_AfterUpdate()

UpdateFilter
Me.Requery
End Sub

Sub 

UpdateFilter()
Dim strFilter As String
strFilter = FilterString()
If Len(strFilter) > 0 Then
  Me.Filter = strFilter
  Me.FilterOn = True
Else
  Me.Filter = ""
  Me.FilterOn = False
End If
End Sub

Function FilterString() As String
Dim strReturn As String
Dim strStart As String
Dim strEnd As String
strReturn = ""
If IsNull(Me!cboStart) Or IsNull(Me!cboEnd) Then GoTo Fn_Exit
strStart = Me!cboStart
strEnd = Me!cboEnd
strReturn = "Month_Worked Between '" & strStart & "' And '" & strEnd & "'"
Fn_Exit:
FilterString = strReturn
End Function
```

But I don't want to show all year and months in combobox so I added new comboboxes (they are called in code as "cmb_YearFrom" and "cmb_YearTo" for Year so I filter months by year selection.

to do this I wrote a code and added in a query
[Forms]![frmOffeneBestellung]![cmb_YearFrom], [Forms]![frmOffeneBestellung]![cmb_YearTo], so comboboxes "year" are used for month selection as a filter

code:

```
Private Sub cmb_YearTo_AfterUpdate()
cboEnd = Null
cboEnd.Requery
Me.Requery
End Sub

Private Sub cmb_YearFrom_AfterUpdate()
cboStart = Null
cboStart.Requery
Me.Requery
End Sub
```

Now it's like this:
"Year:", "From:"
"Year:","To:"

My Problem: For example I can't filter from 06.2021 to 01.2022.
It only works in the same year like from 05.2021 to 06.2021.
How can I fix it, any ideas?
Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: Your values are strings, not dates, so sort and filter is by alpha rules, one character at a time. "01" comes before "06". Solution options: 1) use a complete date value; 2) separate month and year into number values; 3) configure string as yyyy.mm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must convert those text dates to true dates and date expressions, for example:

```vb
strReturn = "CDate(Replace([Month_Worked], '.', '/')) Between #" & Format(Replace(strStart, ".", "/"), "yyyy\/mm\/dd") & "# And #" & Format(Replace(strEnd, ".", "/"), "yyyy\/mm\/dd") & "#"
```

Comment: Thank you very much, now I can choose the time interval. But now my problem is, after using this filter once and when I want to move the filter away (I have a delete button) and choose a time interval again, it gives an error. My delete code is:
Private Sub 
Me.cboStart = ""
Me.cboEnd = ""
Me.cmb_JahrVom = ""
Me.cmb_JahrBis = ""
Me.Requery
End Sub

Because it is not updating my query. The dates in my form are coming from a query (named qryOffeneBestellung). How can I get my form its original state when I remove my time intervall filter ?

Comment: To not use the filter, just turn it off with: `Me.FilterOn = False`. That should automatically requery the form to show all records.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I'm learning a lot thanks to you. Now when I remove the filter, all my data comes back. 
My current problem is this: apart from choosing a time range, I have other filter options, for example depending on the orderer, this is also a combobox (named cmb_Besteller). When a selection is made, it also filters by orderer.

Comment: (I did this with in requery  LIKE " * " & [Forms]![frmOffeneBestellung]![cmb_Besteller] & " * " and in vba

 Private Sub cmb_Besteller_AfterUpdate()
Me.Requery
End Sub. 

And my delete button is like:

Private Sub cmd_LöschBesteller_Click()
Me.cmb_Besteller = ""
Me.cboStart = ""
Me.cboEnd = ""
Me.cmb_JahrVom = ""
Me.cmb_JahrBis = ""
Me.FilterOn = False
Me.Requery
End Sub


I can use time interval and orderer filters together. But when I want to remove all filters, it still doesn't show all my data. How can I solve it?

Comment: You can at any time set property `Filter` to something else, then (again) set `FilterOn` to _True_.